# Cannot borrow in a Rc as mutable

Tags: rust, borrowing, actix-web

First of all I'm new with Rust :-)

The problem:
I want to create a module called RestServer that contain the methods ( actix-web ) to add routes and start the server.

```
struct Route
{
   url: String,
   request: String,
   handler: Box<dyn Fn(HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse>
}


impl PartialEq for Route {
   fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
     self.url == other.url
   }
}

impl Eq for Route {}

impl Hash for Route {
   fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, hasher: &mut H) {
      self.url.hash(hasher);
   }
}
```

this is the route structure, this structure containe the the route url, the request type ( GET, POST etc ) and hanlder is the function that have to catch the request and return a HTTPResponse

```
pub struct RestServer
{
   scopes: HashMap<String, Rc<HashSet<Route>>>,
   routes: HashSet<Route>,
   host: String,
}

impl RestServer {

   pub fn add_route(self, req: &str, funct: impl Fn(HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse + 'static,
                 route: &str, scope: Option<&str>) -> RestServer
   {
       let mut routes_end = self.routes;
       let mut scopes_end = self.scopes;
       let url = self.host;
       let route = Route {
          url: String::from(route),
          request: String::from(req),
          handler: Box::new(funct)
    };

    if let Some(x) = scope {
        if let Some(y) = scopes_end.get(x) {
            let mut cloned_y = Rc::clone(y);
            cloned_y.insert(route);
            scopes_end.insert(String::from(x), cloned_y);
        }else {
            let mut hash_scopes = HashSet::new();
            hash_scopes.insert(route);
            scopes_end.insert(String::from(x), Rc::new(hash_scopes));
        }
    } else {
        routes_end.insert(route);
    }

    RestServer {
        scopes: scopes_end,
        routes: routes_end,
        host: String::from(url)
    }
  }
```

the latest code is the implementation of RestServer. 
The most important part is the **add_route** function, this function receive as paramente the route that is a string, the function handler, the request string and the scope.
First i create the route object.
I check if the scope exist into the HashMap, if yes i have to take the actual scope and update the HashSet.

When i build the code i get the following error

```
   error[E0596]: cannot borrow data in an `Rc` as mutable
   --> interface/src/rest/mod.rs:60:17
   |
60 |                 cloned_y.insert(route);
   |                 ^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
   |
   = help: trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not 
     implemented for `std::rc::Rc<std::collections::HashSet<rest::Route>>`
```

I know that the compiler give me some help but honestly i have no idea how to do that or if i can do with some easy solution.
After a large search in google i found a solution in RefCell, but is not so much clear

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You cannot borrow a reference-counting pointer as mutable; this is because one of the guarantees it provides is only possible if the structure is read-only.

You can, however, get around it, but it will require some signature changes.

## Enter interior mutability

Interior mutability is a concept you may know from other programming languages in the form of mutexes, atomics and synchronization primitives. In practice, those structures allow you to temporarily guarantee that you are the *only* accessor of a given variable.

In Rust, this is particularly good, as it allows us to extract a mutable reference to an interior member from a structure that only requires immutable references to itself to function. Perfect to fit in `Rc`.

Depending on what you need for your needs, you will find the [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) and [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) structures to be exactly what you need for this. These are not thread-safe, but then again, neither is `Rc` so it's not exactly a deal-breaker.

In practice, it works very simply:

```
let data = Rc::new(RefCell::new(true));
{
  let mut reference = data.borrow_mut();
  *reference = false;
}
println!("{:?}", data);
```

[**playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dca128696b2f7d51caa6240d21cf1d83)

(If you ever want the threaded versions, `Arc` replaces `Rc` and `Mutex` or `RwLock` replaces `Cell`/`RefCell`)