# Cannot borrow data in 'Rc' as mutable

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, dereference, raytracing

I've been writing a ray tracer in Rust and I've come across a problem. I have defined the following struct:

```
pub struct HitRecord{
     mat : Rc<RefCell<dyn Material>,
     ...
}
```

The `Material` trait has only one associated function:

```
pub trait Material{
fn scatter(&mut self,r_in : &mut Ray, rec : &HitRecord, attenuation : &mut Color, scattered : &mut Ray) -> bool; 
}
```

That some structs (e.g. `Lambertian` and `Metal`) implement. I don't understand how I'm supposed to call this function from another piece of code:

```
    let mut rec : HitRecord = HitRecord::new(); 

    if world.hit(r, &mut Interval{min : 0.001, max : INFINITY} , &mut rec){
        let mut scattered = Ray::new();
        let mut attenuation = Color::new();
        let temp = rec.mat.clone();

        if temp.scatter(r, &rec, &mut attenuation,&mut scattered) {
            return attenuation * self.ray_color(&mut scattered,depth-1,world);
        }   

        return Color::new();
    }
```

The function call `world.hit()` requires `rec` to be mutable, since it assigns to it. The problem occurs in the second if statement:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow data in an `Rc` as mutable
--> camera.rs:128:16
|
|             if temp.get_mut().scatter(r, &rec, &mut attenuation,&mut scattered) {
|                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
|
= help: trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `Rc<RefCell<dyn material::Material>>`
```

I tried implementing `DerefMut` for `dyn Material` but I got different errors regarding `Deref` not being satisfied and upon implementing that various other errors; I wasn't able to implement it properly. I've also tried switching `Rc<RefCell>` with other things, such as `Rc`, `Box`, `Rc<Box>` to name a few, with fruitless results.  I've searched for [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58599539/cannot-borrow-in-a-rc-as-mutable) with similar error messages but I can't see how they apply to my case, if they do at all.

EDIT:
A minimal example of the problem is as follows:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::borrow::BorrowMut;

struct Stone;
trait Material {
    fn scatter(&mut self, rec : &HitRecord){
        println!("scattering");
    }
}

impl Material for Stone {}

pub struct HitRecord{
    pub mat : Rc<RefCell<dyn Material>>
}

impl HitRecord{
    pub fn new() -> Self{
        Self{
            mat : Rc::new(RefCell::new(Stone)) as Rc<RefCell<dyn Material>>
       }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut f = HitRecord::new();
    // None of these compile
    f.borrow_mut().scatter(&f.mat);
    f.mat.borrow_mut().scatter(&f.mat);
    f.mat.scatter(&f.mat);
}
```

Comment: You need to call `borrow_mut()` on the inner `RefCell` to get a mutable reference to the trait object.

Comment: When i try `if temp.borrow_mut().scatter(r, &rec, &mut attenuation,&mut scattered)` I get
 `method not found in &mut Rc<RefCell<dyn Material>>` so maybe Box is the only way.

Comment: Same thing happens when I wrap it up in another `Box`.

Comment: in your minimal example you should write `let mut f = HitRecord::new();`.  But this does not compile because `HitRecord` does not have `scatter()`

Comment: @ensc You're right about `mut` but even `f.mat.borrow_mut().scatter()` doesn't compile. Nor `f.mat.scatter()`.

Comment: Do **not** include `BorrowMut` unless you want to implement it, that leads to errors like these, you want `Rc::borrow_mut` **not** `BorrowMut::borrow_mut`. [this compiles](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5b062ef36d782ed9a2fdc71bbcc852b7) but is not very likely to be the thing you want.

Comment: @cafce25 Thank you, this does indeed compile, but the in the resulting render all the objects are black. Is this somehow a consequence of this?

Comment: Impossible to tell from what you've shared, I'd say it's likely to be a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're importing `BorrowMut` which also provides a *different* `borrow_mut` method, but you want to call `Rc::borrow_mut` so remove `use std::borrow::BorrowMut` and write the following:

```rust
fn main() {
    let f = HitRecord::new();
    f.mat.borrow_mut().scatter(&f);
}
```

Note though, that you cannot access `rec.mat` from inside that specific `scatter` call in any meaningful way because it's already borrowed exclusively so any attempt to borrow it again will panic.

---

It is *extremely* rare that you need to import `BorrowMut` especially in combination with `Rc` and `RefCell` you can usually just use the corresponding syntax: `a.borrow_mut()` → `&mut a`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `get_mut` makes no sense: the purpose of `get_mut` is to trivially provide a mutable reference to the wrapped value *when you have a mutable reference to the refcell*:

```
pub fn get_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T
```

But you don't have that, `Rc` will only hand out shared references ([it only implements `Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#impl-Deref-for-Rc%3CT%3E))<sup>1</sup>.

The normal way to get a mutable reference out of a `RefCell` is [`borrow_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow_mut), which checks at runtime that there is no outstanding borrow (mutable or not) then returns one. You don't even need to clone the `rec.mat`, unless you need to store a new instance.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8801c8388486b54739bbc8ffe14bc1c8

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Stone;
trait Material {
    fn scatter(&mut self) {
        println!("scattering");
    }
}
impl Material for Stone {}

fn main() {
    let f = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Stone)) as Rc<RefCell<dyn Material>>;
    f.borrow_mut().scatter();
}
```

---

1: except for [`Rc::get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.get_mut) but that's far from normal use, it'll only work if that's the sole outstanding reference; and [`make_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.make_mut) which will clone the internal value but that's not usually the case (or desirable) if you're using `Rc`.

Comment: I think your example misses the use of `HitRecord` which may be the culprit. I've edited the post to include a minimal example of the problem.